# SELECT matching dates from a timestamp with time zone column

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, select

I have a timestamp with time zone column within which I'd like to run a query returning all matching dates. eg. I want all rows which have a timestamp with date 2019-09-30. I'm trying something like this but haven't been able to figure it out:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
x='1277' AND
date='2019-09-30 21:40:01.316240 +00:00'::DATE;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options:

1. range search:

   ```
   WHERE timestampcol >= TIMESTAMPTZ '2019-09-30'
     AND timestampcol < (TIMESTAMPTZ '2019-09-30' + INTERVAL '1 day')
   ```

   The proper index to make this fast is

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON atable (timestampcol);
   ```
2. conversion to `date`:

   ```
   WHERE CAST(timestampcol AS date) = '2019-09-30'
   ```

   The proper index to make this fast is

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON atable ((CAST(timestampcol AS date)));
   ```

Both methods work equally well. The second method has a shorter `WHERE` clause, but a specialized index that maybe no other query can benefit from.

Comment: I'm going to be doing this with 3 dates: matching three timestamp columns in this way. Which one do you think I should I go for?

Comment: I would use the first form, because of the more generally useful index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use such a collation among your date converted column value and fixed date value :

```
with tab( x, date ) as
(
 select 1277, '2019-09-30 21:40:01.316240 +00:00'::timestamp with time zone union all
 select 1278, '2019-09-29 21:40:01.316240 +00:00'::timestamp with time zone  
)
select *
  from tab
 where date::date = date'2019-09-30';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=d57ff1fca4382c688e9255c7029ba06c)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with postgresql, but the following page https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html indicates that there is an optional precision value ***p*** that is used to specify the number of fractional digits retained in the seconds field. How was the data type configured for your ***date*** field? Is the timestamp column being stored as an eight byte integer or a floating-point number? If the later, the effective limit of precision might be less than 6. All of this info is on the above linked page.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, as they have been mentioned, and may vary depending on the data type of your field named "date".

For example,

1. Turn your field to date, returning format 'yyyy-mm-dd':

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE x='1277' AND date::DATE='2019-09-30';`

"date" just after field name.

2. Convert it to char and retrieve 10 characters:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE x='1277' AND LEFT(date::varchar,10)='2019-09-30';`

3. Like the previous:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE x='1277' AND to_char(date,'yyyymmdd')='20190930';`

And there are many others. For more specific info, you have to check PostgreSQL documentation to check which one is best for you or post more information in order we can guess more about your problem.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-datetime.html